# What is this white furry pest?

Tags: pests

This is a basil plant growing in a hydroponics kit in my kitchen. I'm not sure how it got there but it appears to be a pest that has gotten in somehow. The leaves started to wilt and die.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That looks like evidence of aphids to me.

Comment: Or possibly thrips.